# A monotone sequence and finite series sum - characterization

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Is there a characterization of the set of all sequences $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of real numbers such that
$$1\leq x_{n}\leq x_{n+1}$$
for all $n\geq 1$, and
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x_{n}^{2}}\leq 1.$$

( A trivial example for such sequence could be $\{\frac{\pi n}{\sqrt{6}}\}$)

**Edit**:  It would be good to have such sequences which increase "slowly"?

Comment: More examples $$x_n = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 6}\sum_{i=0}^k a_in^i$$ where $k\ge 1, a_i \ge 0 ~ (a_k > 0)$

Comment: I think it holds for all $x_n \ge \dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt 6} n$.

Comment: So you can take any polynomial of the above form in my first comment. They increase "slowly".

Comment: Sounds good!  How bigger/smaller choice of  $k$ affect the monotonocity speed of $x_{n}$?

Comment: I posted an answer concatenating and extending my comments a bit

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, using the identity
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 6}n\right)^2} = 1$$
Now by comparison, we see that the statement holds for all $x_n \ge \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 6}n$. Because
$$\begin{align} 
x_n \ge \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 6}n &\implies \frac{1}{x_n^2} \le \frac{1}{\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 6}n\right)^2} \\
&\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{x_n^2} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 6}n\right)^2} = 1
\end{align}$$

Since you want a class of such sequences which grow slowly, you can take any polynomial of the form
$$\boxed{x_n = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 6}\sum_{i=0}^k a_in^i}  \tag{$\ge\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 6}n$}$$ where $a_i \ge 0, ~ (a_k \ne 0)$ and $k\ge 1$.

Of course, the larger you choose $k$, the faster the sequence increases as demonstrated in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you very much. But I have a question: if we have two series such that $\sum a_{n} \leq \sum b_{n}$, does this imply that $a_{n} \leq b_{n}$ (since I guess you used this fact) The opposit direction is known to be true.

Comment: @MathPro No, I did not use that fact, that is wrong. Actually, I did not compare any series there.

Comment: @MathPro If you were about comparing the boxed expression with $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 6}n$, it was because of the positiveness of $a_i$'s.

Comment: Ok. So I think the statement "Now by comparison, we see that the statement holds for all $ x_n \geq \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6} } n$." is not obvious!

Comment: @Mathpro Is it ok after the edit?

Comment: It is Ok, but the conclusion is not "if and only if"! Is it possible to have other forms of such sequences?

Comment: @MathPro As you asked for slower ones the above examples work. Definitely, there are other forms such as exponential sequences but I don't know the general form of all solutions right now.